# Calculate the contact length between segments of image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have images made of four colors. Each color represents a specific matter phase. I can segment the image based on the color and calculate the perimeter of the segmented images. Now, I need to calculate the contact length between different phases. [An example of the image is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXZAj.png). For example, the contact length between the blue phase and the yellow phase is very small, while blue and gray phases have significant contact.

```
% aa is the image  
oil = (aa(:,:,3)==255);
rock =(aa(:,:,2)==179);
gas =(aa(:,:,2)==255);
water =(aa(:,:,2)==0 && aa(:,:,3)==0);

O = bwboundaries(oil);
R = bwboundaries(rock);
G = bwboundaries(gas);
W = bwboundaries(water);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code that I eventual wrote. The results look correct.

```
    % aa is the image  
oil = (aa(:,:,3)==255);
rock =(aa(:,:,2)==179);
gas =(aa(:,:,2)==255);
water =(aa(:,:,2)==0 && aa(:,:,3)==0);

phases(1,:,:)=RockBW;
phases(2,:,:)=WaterBW;
phases(3,:,:)=OilBW;
phases(4,:,:)=GasBW;

outMat = ContactMatrix(phases);
```

The function ContactMatrix is shown in following:

```
function [ContactMat] = ContactMatrix(phases)
%CONTACTMATRIX measure the contact area between diferent phases

% The output is a 2D matrix which shows the lengths

%         Phase1, Phase2, Phase 3 
%phase1     L1      L2      L4
%Phase2     L2      L3      L5
%Phase3     L4      L5      L6

% L1 is zero
% L2 is the contact area of Phase1 and Phase2

nph = size(phases,1);

imSize = size(phases(1,:,:));
xmax =imSize(2);
ymax = imSize(3);
% Idealy we need a check for all sizes :) 
ContactMat = zeros(nph);

for i=1:1:nph
   counts = zeros(1,nph);
   dd2=bwmorph(squeeze(phases(i,:,:)),'dilate',1);
   B = bwboundaries(dd2);
   nB = size(B,1);
   coefs=1:1:nph;
   coefs(i)=[];
   for j=1:1:nB
        fd = B{j};
        % Ignore the points at boundary of image
        fd(fd(:,1)==1 | fd(:,1)==xmax | fd(:,2)==1 | fd(:,2)==ymax,:)=[];
        nL = size(fd,1);

        for k=1:1:nL(1)
            %bufCheck=false(nph-1,1);
               mat=fd(k,1) + (fd(k,2)-1)*xmax;
               bufCheck = phases(coefs,mat);
               counts(coefs)=counts(coefs)+bufCheck';
        end
   end 
   ContactMat(i,coefs)=counts(coefs);
end
ContactMat = 0.5*(ContactMat+ContactMat');
end
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it counts boundary pixels as a proxy for boundary length. A boundary at 45 degrees will have a number of pixels proportional to `length/sqrt(2)`, whereas a boundary at 0 degrees it will be proportional to `length`. That is, your measure is biased depending on the angle of the boundary in the image.

Comment: Yes, the calculation has error. I added a few more lines of code to calculate the interface using the regionprops('perimeter').

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way would be to iterate through each pixel in your image and based on that pixel value, and the value of the pixel to the right of it, increment a variable representing that phase transition contact length count, if there is a phase transition. Then do the same for the value below your pixel. Do this for every pixel in the image, except edge conditions.

A more efficient way would be to do rows and columns at a time, and increment counters as you do this.

Or you could make multiple matrices of your image, shifted by one pixel, and do comparisons looking for your phase transitions which end up with binary matrix results and simply sum these result binary matrices

Comment: I used bwboundaries to calculate the boundaries of the region. Then, the code traces along the boundaries. I also used 'dilate to expand the region for each phase, so the boundary calculated by bwboundaries will be in neighboring phase.